# NGINX proxy pass can't find static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to host my website and CMS on the same Ubuntu server and am trying to access them both, but I am struggling with the configuration. The website is currently a simple HTML page, and the CMS is a Node app. The CMS app has an index page on `http://localhost:1337/` and a dashboard page on `http://localhost:1337/admin`. With my current setup I can only view the index page on `WEBSITE.eu/admin`. When I try to go to `WEBSITE.eu/admin/admin` it is unable to find the static files (json / js files, etc.) to render the page.

So in short what I want to do is: `WEBSITE.eu/admin` location to point to `http://localhost:1337/admin` so the CMS dashboard is shown.

My current server block config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/WEBSITE/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name WEBSITE.eu www.WEBSITE.eu;

        location /admin {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/admin/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';` are probably useless in your case

Comment: `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337$request_uri;` should work fine in your case

Comment: and now you need to find what files are required out of /admin/ for the admin to be usable ( /img/ /css/ /vendor/ etc...) and proxy pass those too

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;`

Comment: @AntonyGibbs Do you happen to have an example? In my network tab I see my .js files are being downloaded but parsing the .js files is still going wrong. This only happens when I do the proxy on `/admin`. When I proxy `/` it all works fine.

Comment: @RichardSmith Same thing as my reply above happens.

Comment: If you are trying to proxy `/admin/` to `/`, you should use `location /admin/` (with a trailing `/`) and `proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;` (also with a trailing `/`)

Comment: As Richard pointed out this `location /admin/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/admin/; ...` should work

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks alot, the trailing slash in proxy_pass was also my problem. But why is it behaving like that, can I read anything about it somewhere in the docs?

Comment: @0x45 see the [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), particularly the sections "If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI" and "If proxy_pass is specified without a URI".